# Are cached RDDs resilient to graceful worker shutdown?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a (very) small Spark cluster which is used as a 'sandpit' environment by several people. Occasionally, I need to restart the worker nodes in the course of maintaining the cluster.

If a running job is working off an RDD which has been `.cache()`'d, and the worker is stopped gracefully (by running `./stop-slave.sh` on that node), what happens to the portion of the cached RDD?

The two scenarios I can think of (assuming the storage level for the RDD is `MEMORY_ONLY`, with no replication) are that:

1. The worker distributes its portion of the RDD across the other workers;
2. The portion of the RDD held by the worker is lost, and must be recomputed.

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) suggests that the partition would be recomputed, but it's unclear whether this covers 'graceful' worker shutdown.

Comment: Good question. From the documentation, I can nothing but infer that whenever a node is shut down (gracefully or not), the RDD must be recomputed in any case.